# What is current best-practice for using MP4s/video on the web?

Tags: html, video, mp4, web-standards, video-embedding

I am making a site that has videos as a fairly large component.

I've got the word that we want to focus on mp4 format/files. I just want to know what the best standards-based way of including mp4 videos is these days? Many of the things I run into online I'm not sure if it is outdated. We want it to work on mobile devices, as well as most desktop browsers, and ideally without having to install strange plug-ins.. but even better would be not having to code our own player.

I have heard that html5 supports direct video embedding, but I don't know how to gracefully degrade that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use HTML5, with at least two source files for every file.
If you use the several-source form, the browser will download only the one it can play (w/o killing bandwidth.)
Something like this:

```
<body>
<video width='320' height='240' controls>
<source src='video.webm' type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
<source src='video.ogv' type='video/ogv; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
</body>
```

With these two formats you've covered most needs (they are standard).
Also, you should also add some Flash fallback for non-compliant browsers (IE8-).